# How to rewrite .htaccess with nginx

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx

I have apache with ngnix as a reverse proxy.
I have

```
RewriteRule ^thumb/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) thumb.php?w=$1&h=$2&src=$3
RewriteRule ^medias/(.*) files.php?file=$1
```

How to rewrite theme in nginx ?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential difference between Apache and `nginx` URIs, is that all `nginx` URIs begin with a leading `/`.

You should try:

```
rewrite ^/thumb/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) /thumb.php?w=$1&h=$2&src=$3? last;
rewrite ^/medias/(.*) /files.php?file=$1? last;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with the categories